# Checking if a file exists in java

Tags: java, file, exists

So the following program should take in an input and output file as command line arguments.

```
class FileCopy
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String infile = null;
    String outfile = null;
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    

    if (args.length >= 2) //both files given via command line
    {
        infile = args[0];
        if (fileExists(infile) == false)
        {
            infile = getInputFile();
        }
        outfile = args[1];
    }
    else if (args.length == 1) //input file given via command line
    {
        infile = args[0];
        outfile = getOutputFile(infile);
    }
    else //no files given on command line
    {
        infile = getInputFile();
        outfile = getOutputFile(infile);
    }

    //create file objects to use
    File in = new File(infile);
    File out = new File(outfile);

    /*
     *rest of code
     */
}

//get the input file from the user if given file does not exist
public static String getInputFile() //throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String fileName = null;
    boolean haveFile = false;

    while(haveFile == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid filename for input:");
        System.out.print(">> ");
        try
        {
            fileName = stdin.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e);
        }
        haveFile = fileExists(fileName);
    }

    return fileName;    
}

//get the output file and test things
public static String getOutputFile(String infile)
{
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    File input = new File(infile);
    String filename = null;
    boolean more = true;
    while(more)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid filename for output:");
        System.out.print(">> ");
        try
        {
            filename = stdin.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e);
        }
        File output = new File(filename);
        if (output.exists())
        {
            more = false;
        }
        if (filename == infile)
        {
            int selection;
            String inputString = null;

            System.out.println("The output file given matches the input file. Please choose an option:");
            System.out.println("1) Enter new filename");
            System.out.println("2) Overwrite existing file");
            System.out.println("3) Backup existing file");
            System.out.print(">> ");
            try
            {
                inputString = stdin.readLine();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e);
            }
            selection = Integer.valueOf(inputString);
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1: //new filename
                case 2: //overwrite
                case 3: //backup
                default: System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//check the given file to see if it exists in the current working directory
public static boolean fileExists(String n)
{
    return (new File(n)).exists();
}
}
```

Comment: You could simplify this down to just `public static boolean fileExists(String  n) { return n.length > 0 && new File(n).exists(); }` And are you positive that this "input.txt" is in your classpath? Try creating a new file in that method and see where it creates it.

Comment: not a code problem in `fileExists`, look for your problem somewhere else. BTW if you want to check your areguments are OK, you have to check `n!=null` too

Comment: Does the string you pass in contain the drive letter too? I usually start out by specifying the entire path like "c:/temp/myfile.txt" then once you know the method works you can look further. Print out the value of n when it runs, is the file in your target folder or bin folder? That's normally the working directory when it executes.

Comment: the way input.txt is being given is via the command line, i'm running `java FileCopy.java input.txt` and then pulling it from the `args[]` array in main (which is required for this program).

Comment: and no, the string does not contain the drive letter or full path, its only the filename. The way I understand `file.exists()` is that if the file being checked is in the same directory as the java program then the full path isn't needed, or shouldnt be

Comment: @Logan also, i just tried entering the full filepath, it does not work

Comment: It sounds like you don't know for sure that your file is in the same directory. Like I said in my previous comment, just do a `new File(n).createNewFile();` and see if it's in the directory you were expecting.

Comment: and for better help faster, include complete information -- in this case, tell us what file you are entering, perhaps an image of the directory listing.  Is it Unix-based, are you sure about letter case?  As others have said, the code is correct, there is a problem somewhere else *in what you are doing*.

Comment: @Austin i put that in to see what happened, and a file was not created.

Comment: @rcook I have no idea what im doing, i didnt know if the code was right from the get go, and didnt know other information was going to be necessary. I am running Windows 7, using Java 1.6u34, I am entering the string `java FileCopy input.txt` via the command line (where FileCopy is the class file), and taking `input.txt` out of the args[] array in main. If you want i'll post the whole program as it stands.

Comment: @ZakParks Maybe it was created in a directory that you aren't aware of. I don't think I've heard of createNewFile failing.

Comment: @Austin nope its not working. Using Windows 7's global search bar in the start menu, input.txt isnt found anywhere on my computer. Which is indeed quite odd.

Comment: @ZakParks You should do a `System.out.println("fileExists: " + n);` in the beginning of your method to see if something isn't going on with the variable. (To make sure it's getting the args correctly)

Comment: @Austin and now i discover that the program isn't even making it to fileExists... I'm going to put the full code in the OP, maybe that will let people find the issue better.

Comment: @ZakParks in getOutputFile, you're doing a `System.exit(0)`, which will close out of your program. That's why nothing is happening.

Comment: @Austin But the program never executes that far? The flow pattern I have had is main -> getInputFile -> forever stay in while loop. The program never stops executing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One detail that I believe you have missed:

When your program has only one argument (`args.length == 1`), i.e. when only the input file is defined, `fileExists()` is not called at all; `infile` is set to `args[0]` with no validation at all. You should probably add a specific check as you have done for the two-argument case.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar problem too.  I was working under eclipse, and had to specify "src/file.txt" with my current directory having a file named "file" in the src directory.

*Note: It was not named "file.txt" (this causes the string to be interpreted as "file.txt.txt"!).*

Try testing against this program here assuming you have a file named "file" in your "src" directory:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileChecker {

public static boolean Exists( String file ) 
{ 
    System.out.println("File being checked: " + file);
    return( (file.length()) > 0 && (new File(file).exists()) );
}

public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    File dir = new File("src");

    System.out.println("List of files in source directory: ");
    if( dir.isDirectory()){
        File[] filenames = dir.listFiles();
        for( Object file : filenames ) {
            System.out.println(file.toString());
        }

    }
    else
        System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");

    if(FileChecker.Exists("src/file.txt"))
        System.out.println("File exists");
    else
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
}

}
```

It will print out the current files in source directory so you can see whether the file is really there or not, then you can test if it actually exists.  Works on my end.